# How to flat in one row Dataframe and concatenate them

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have several Dataframes with the same structure :

|  | 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **0** | TITLE | TITLE1 |
| **1** | A | A1 |
| **2** | B | B1 |
| **3** | C | C1 |
| **4** | D | D1 |
| **5** | E | E1 |

|  | 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **0** | TITLE | TITLE2 |
| **1** | A | A2 |
| **2** | B | B2 |
| **3** | C | C2 |
| **4** | D | D2 |
| **5** | E | E2 |

My goal is to have :

| TITLE | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **TITLE1** | A1 | B1 | C1 | D1 | E1 |
| **TITLE2** | A2 | B2 | C2 | D2 | E2 |

How can I transform my Dataframes to flat them and concatenate them like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with transpose and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df11 = df1.set_index(0).T
df22 = df2.set_index(0).T

df = pd.concat([df11,df22]).set_index('TITLE')
print (df)
0        A   B   C   D   E
TITLE                     
TITLE1  A1  B1  C1  D1  E1
TITLE2  A2  B2  C2  D2  E2
```

Or transpose after `concat` with `axis=1`:

```
df11 = df1.set_index(0)
df22 = df2.set_index(0)

df = pd.concat([df11,df22], axis=1).T.set_index('TITLE')
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!